# Should a Text File be stored in my SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, wcf, sql-server-2008

We are using several text files as Templates to create the results of a WCF Data Services - Service Operation call.

The text files are each less than 3000 Bites Max.

What are the pros and cons of storing my template files on the file system with the WCF Data Services files vs storing them in a SQL Server 2008 R2 server?

Comment: is there any particular reason why you would prefer to store the file as opposed to the file's text content? Curious, that's all

Comment: 3K is very small. Even in versions prior to SQL 2005 you could put 8K of data in a varchar. So this is really a more generic question: "Where should I put my configuration data. In a file or in a database?" There's a ton written on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to SQL Server 2008, I recommended strongly against storing large objects like text files in the database.  It tended to slow down access and made them generally harder to work with.  Instead, I generally recommended storing links to the files in question.

Of course, this meant that the database would not protect the files in the event someone deleted something they shouldn't and the files needed to be backed up and transferred separately from the database.

With SQL Server 2008, I think many of the former problems have been overcome using the filestream functions and I think that storing files using filestream can be quite useful at times.  It continues to store the actual data outside the database, which avoids many of the former complications.  But it still binds the two together and permits the database to protect the files rather than just relying on the links in the database to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of pros and cons for either storage method. Nowadays (my opinion has changed, and may change again some day), I'd focus on security and managability.

- If it is sensitive data, you might get a bit more security by storing them in the database. If nothing else, it might be more difficult to hack a database than a file system. If security is not so important, it can be easier/simpler to store it on the OS.
- For managing, if the data gets updated (and how frequently does that happen), how easy is it to update? One instance in a database is simpler to update (or corrupt...) than an instance on each of however many servers are in your web farm. (1 server, no problem, 20 servers, possible headache.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to store the data directly in the database. This makes it even faster to access because a database is more efficient in reading and generally handling data. You could always store movies in databases - that's no problem. Then it's also possible to stream large data.

For security reasons existing more as enough options to configure your database. And if you cluster your database - this is even more scalable.